# If I edit my questions, will they be assessed by an automated bot or a moderator?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I have edited the majority of my questions to be more specific and I would like to know how long the timeframe (if there is one) is for an unban.

Comment: It's not an automated process, it's supposed to happen organically after you've improved your content, where eventually people who see your content will (hopefully/upvote it

Comment: Note that editing a post bumps it to the front page, which gives people the opportunity to see it and vote on it. Also, the 1st edit after a post is closed sends it to the Reopen review queue, where people may vote to open it if it has been improved sufficiently. So make sure that 1st edit is substantial!

Comment: @PM2Ring so after the first edit there is no chance that a question can be opened?

Comment: The chance is higher after the first edit, because of the Reopen queue. But that doesn't mean there's no chance later on. Every edit bumps a post to the front page, but please don't do lots of trivial edits just to bump your questions, that won't make a good impression on the community.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: That doesn't really work on a site with 8,000 new questions per day (one every 27 seconds on average, roll off after about 35 minutes (effectively less than that))

Comment: @PeterMortensen That's true, although it's not *quite* that bad because a lot of power users don't look at the front page, they look at active questions in their favourite tags. But yes, it is a problem, and the company is trying to improve the situation via the various ongoing changes to the closing & review processes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your questions will not be assessed by a bot and are unlikely to be assessed by a moderator either.

There are few moderators compared to ordinary users so while moderators can look at active questions it's far more likely that ordinary users will see your edits and react to them.

To be unbanned you need to have your existing questions upvoted, it's not possible to say how long that will take as it depends on what tags your questions have, how good an edit you make and how the people reading your updated question feel about its quality.

Comment: That makes sense. So reputation has 0 involvement when it comes to an unban?